# Prove if $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$, then $\frac{\sin(x^2+x+1)}{f(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove if $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$, then $\frac{\sin(x^2+x+1)}{f(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$

**attempt**

we know $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, -1\leq \sin(x^2+x+1)\leq1$ so

$$-\frac{1}{f(x)}\leq \frac{\sin(x^2+x+1)}{f(x)} \leq \frac{1}{f(x)} $$

since $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{f(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$
therefore according to squeeze theorem $\frac{\sin(x^2+x+1)}{f(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$

Is my attempt correct? if not give me some hints.

Comment: It works. You’d have to also show that the squeeze theorem does hold for limits at infinity but that isn’t difficult at all.

Comment: @Abhi Do I need to prove $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{f(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as $ x  \rightarrow \infty$ this part?

Comment: Indeed you do but I assumed you had already done that and in any case, the proof takes up at most 3 lines or so.

Comment: @Abhi Can I use contrapositive to prove it? is it method to prove it?

Comment: You can prove it directly using the definition. So, you know that if $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. That means that $f(x)$ can be made as large as we want it to be at infinity. Then, it follows that $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ can be made as small as we want it to be at infinity. Now, translate this into $\epsilon-\delta$ mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: got it thank you

Comment: You’re welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is right. In general when encountering functions like $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ and $g(x)$ is bounded from both above and below and $f(x)$ is not bounded, we usually use the squeeze theorem to get the desired results.

Comment: got it thank you (+1)